# SplayTreeMap is removing duplicate after ordering a Map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following Map:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> data = {'two': {'date' : 2}, 'zero': {'date' : 1}, 'three': {'date' : 3}, 'one': {'date' : 2},};
```

I'd like to order it by `date`.
I'm trying this code:

```dart
final sorted = SplayTreeMap<String,dynamic>.from(data, (a, b) => data[a]["date"].compareTo(data[b]["date"]));
```

with output:

```dart
{'two': {'date' : 2}, 'zero': {'date' : 1}, 'three': {'date' : 3}}
```

How could I avoid deletion of duplicate value ('date': 2 appeared two times but now in `sorted` appears only once)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`SplayTreeMap` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html):

> Keys of the map are compared using the `compare` function passed in the constructor, both for ordering and for equality.

Your comparison function considers the entries `'two': {'date' : 2}` and `'one': {'date' : 2}` as equal, so `SplayTreeMap` assumes that they have equivalent keys and overwrites one with the other.

You could (sort of) fix this by changing your comparison function to have a strict ordering; that is, sort by the key if the `'date`s are equal:

```dart
  final sorted = SplayTreeMap<String, dynamic>.from(data, (a, b) {
    var valueA = data[a]?['date'];
    var valueB = data[b]?['date'];
    if (valueA != null && valueB != null) {
      var result = valueA.compareTo(valueB);
      if (result != 0) {
        return result;
      }
    } 
    return a.compareTo(b);
  });
```

Note that the comparison function is used when doing lookups, so I had to add some extra null-checks to handle lookups of non-existent keys.

That said, **I caution against the above code**.  A `SplayTreeMap` is meant to sort a `Map` by *keys*.  However, you want your `Map` sorted by *values*.  This is inherently problematic because the *keys* of a `Map` should be immutable (if one of them changed, lookups would be broken since the value would still be stored in the original location), but *values* of a `Map` can change.  Making the order dependent on values also means that lookups by keys won't be efficient.

Instead, you'd probably be better off converting your `Map` to a `List`, sorting that, and creating a new `Map`:

```dart
  var sorted = Map.fromEntries(data.entries.toList()
    ..sort((a, b) => a.value['date'].compareTo(b.value['date'])));
```

Comment: Tank you for the answer, I tested your first code and it is working nice with my usecase. However I can't truly understand why it could fail and prefer not to use it.

Comment: @faccio As I said, I do not recommend using the `SplayTreeMap` code.  It is inappropriate for your use case.

Comment: copy that. Even though my Maps are far more complex than the samples I posted here, with other fields and SubMap, so I think I can't use your second suggested approach...

Comment: @faccio It should be easy to adjust the `sort` callback to deal with other fields and nested `Map`s. (Using a `SplayTreeMap` would be no different in that regard.) Keeping a `Map` in sorted order by values is fundamentally problematic, so if that's really what you want, you'll need to explicitly enforce an order whenever you make any change to the `Map` values.  Otherwise you should probably should change your design to make the fields you want to sort on actually part of the keys instead.  Making a custom class for the keys would be a lot easier.